# Autocomplete with Search as you type anywhere matching and validation

Tags: javascript, php, html

The following code works perfectly to display the autocomplete options in an HTML form field:

```js
function fruitautocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) {
      return false;
    }
    currentFocus = -1;
    /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    /*for each item in the array...*/
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
      if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        /*make the matching letters bold:*/
        b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
        b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
        /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
        /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          /*close the list of autocompleted values,
          (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
          closeAllLists();
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
      increase the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus++;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
      /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
      decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus--;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var fruitlist = [
  "Apple",
  "Mango",
  "Pear",
  "Banana",
  "Berry"
];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myFruitList" element, and pass along the fruit array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myFruitList"), fruitlist);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}


/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */

input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}


/* Hide all steps by default: */

.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}


/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */

.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */

.step.finish {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}
```

```html
<form id="regForm" action="/submit_page.php">
  <h1>Your Nutrition Needs:</h1>
  <div class="tab">Your Fruit:
    <p class="autocomplete">
      <input id="myFruitList" type="text" name="fruit" placeholder="Start typing your fruit name"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

All good and working. And I want to enhance it with following requirements:

1. When a user starts typing (at least 1 character), only then the matching entries appear. Is it possible to display the whole fruitlist when the cursor is placed on the empty field (making it easier for user to scroll and click on the existing fruit of his choice)?
2. Right now, the code works perfectly for matching START of the string (like, typing "b" will display list containing Banana and Berry. But what I need is matching ANYWHERE in the string (like, typing "a" should show list of Apple, Mango, Pear and Banana  - as all contain A)
3. Even though an autocomplete value is selected, (like "Banana"), the user can currently still type and modify it - like after typing B and selecting "Banana", they can further type to make it "Bananaxyzabc" or simply type whatever they want irrespective of what autocomplete shows. Can the field validation be restricted to allow only what is shown in autocomplete values list?

Comment: For (1): load all data into the select box immediately when the form is loaded. For (2): change the selection criteria to `like '%xxxxx%'` instead of `like 'xxxxx%'`. For (3): change the construct to select box instead of input box. BTW, what did you attempt regarding the three points you mentioned ?? Please show the revised code you have.

Comment: @KenLee - for 2) I tried changing "if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase())" to "if (arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) !=-1)" and similar combos, but those aren't working. Have no clue about 1) and 3), hence the Q. I'm not that good in Javascript :-((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for functionality which is on the "Symbol" field of the form on this page: https://zerodha.com/margin-calculator/SPAN/

It has the standard drop-down, when cursor place it shows all possible entries (1) plus a search box, it does anywhere string search match (2), and may be (3) is also available.
Check its source code to see if that helps.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks @levent001 (+1 for that weblink). Its what I need. However, I've checked the source code of that page and also all the .js files it refers to, but unable to locate the exact function that achieves it. (Sorry, my limited JS knowledge). I am unable to locate a function called "scrip[]" which seems to be associated with that 'Symbol' field (<select class="in" name="scrip[]" id="scrip">). Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a simple answer, and its a moral obligation on my part to post it for everyone's benefit :-)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>


<hr>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
</script>
```

For more details, check https://select2.org/ documentation